# pthread_kill doesnt kill thread C linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

i am making a small project which will be incorporated into larger project. basically what it does is keeps track of threads that are created by way of adding them to a main struct which keeps track of what the thread does (its main function) and its pthread_t id. the other struct keeps track of the data to be passed to the function and the element number of where the pthread_t id is stored inside threads[]. its a bit micky mouse and it jumps around a bit but it all works besides when it is time to kill the thread. i get no segfaults and no errors and the program finishes fine, but the thread does not get killed when pthread_kill() is called (the function returns 0 meaning no error and it worked) although the thread continues to run until the main application returns.

Comment: `strace` is your friend.

Comment: Why are you trying to kill a thread anyway? If the thread is doing work you want it to do, why would you want to kill it? If the thread is doing work you don't want it to do, fix it so it only does work you want it to do. And if the thread has no work to do, code it so it ends itself.

Comment: the functions in my main application are coded in such a matter where they will exit the thread gracefully, but during certain events i have to forcefully terminate the thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pthread_kill()` will not kill a thread. The only difference with `kill()` is that the signal is handled by the designated thread and not handled while that thread has the signal masked (see `pthread_sigmask()`). A signal like `SIGTERM` will by default still terminate the entire process.

If you are considering to call `pthread_exit()` from a signal handler, you should probably use `pthread_cancel()` instead.

Cancellation is safe if all code that may be cancelled cooperates (or the code that calls it disables cancellation for the time). Most libraries do not care about this, though.

A safer method is to ask the thread to exit without any force, such as by sending a special message to it (if the thread normally processes messages).

Alternatively, don't bother to kill any threads and just call `_exit()`, `_Exit()` or `quick_exit()`.

Comment: Note that `pthread_exit` is not async signal safe, so the only way you can call it from a signal handler is if you ensure that signals are blocked whenever calling async-signal-unsafe functions.

Answer (score 4):

From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_kill.html

> As in kill(), if sig is zero, error checking is performed but no signal is actually sent.

so the following

> pthread_kill(threads[i].tID, 0);

Wont actually kill the thread. You need to use an actual signal to kill a thread. A list of signals can be found here:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/signal.h.html

Comment: so i should send SIGKILL to my thread to make it kill? i was a bit confused about the signals and though sending '0' would mean exit with no errors or something around those lines

Comment: SIGKILL would force the thread to be killed. You could also look at using SIGTERM to kill a thread. http://rackerhacker.com/2010/03/18/sigterm-vs-sigkill/ Has a bit more information on the differences between KILL and TERM.

Comment: A signal can't kill a thread either. If it kills anything, it will kill the whole process.